# python and conda: what to do if a package (openssl=1.1.1b=h1de35cc_0) is not found?

Tags: python, conda

I cloned a project where the `environment.yml` file contains, for example

```
- openssl=1.1.1b=h1de35cc_0
```

When I try to create the env I see a lot of not resolved packages

```
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:
....
- openssl=1.1.1b=h1de35cc_0
```

I added, from another SO question, the 'free' entry to channel list

```
channels:
  - defaults
  - free
```

Nothing changes

I manually searched from console and I looked for 1.1.1b version

```
openssl                       1.1.1b      h0c8e037_0  pkgs/main
openssl                       1.1.1b      h0c8e037_1  pkgs/main
openssl                       1.1.1b      he774522_0  pkgs/main
openssl                       1.1.1b      he774522_1  pkgs/main
```

There is not a version 1.1.1b with h1de35cc_0. I don't know what this hash is... also.

What can I do? Can I simply replace 1.1.1b with a he774522_1  , for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply try to remove the `h1de35cc_0` part (what is after the version number), as these are further specifications for exact packages which are sometimes too specific to be resolved on another OS, python version etc.